# What is the difference between quiet and quiescent?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between quiet and quiescent (adjectives)?

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Comment: I generally find explanation by a native speaker more in depth than a dictionary can say, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: @Pinch this website is just the right place to ask, so thank you for the question. But dictionaries are complied by native speakers (in most cases). Most importantly, they are compiled by professional linguists. As for native speakers, they are not always good at explanation. I'm a Japanese learner and when I ask native speakers about the differences between "wa" and "ga", they often say, "Oh, what a good question! Well, I'm not sure...". Please don't underestimate the power of a good dictionary. It's a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone or something that is ***quiescent*** is **quiet** and **inactive** (mind that the word is literary and not used as frequently as "quiet" is). For example:

> *Strikes were headed by groups of workers who had previously been quiescent* (= they were not so active and didn't express their
>   dissatisfaction).

***"Quiet"*** can describe a person, thing, place, situation, time or even colors (consult the [Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quiet) for all the meanings).

If it comes to making **little noise**, "quiet" is commonly used:

> *Tania kept the children reasonably quiet and contented* (= the children didn't make much noise).

So, if you are quiet, you don't make noise or you don't say anything at all. If you are quiescent, you are inactive, you "go with the flow".